# Can I get add_filter() to work with apply_filters()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that I am developing. In my plugin, I add social media share buttons to the single.php content area using the following code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'myFunction');
function myFunction($content) {
    // modify the content stuff goes here    
    return $content
}
```

It works on hundreds of sites so far without a glitch. I have however found one customer whose site is not outputting the content. His site is using the following code to output the content on the single.php page:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

As a result, my filter is not used, or at least it appears to not be being used because it is not adding any of my function's modifications to his content area.

Why isn't my filter being applied to his content? Can I modify something to make this work? What am I missing?

Comment: did you try adding priority? like `add_filter('the_content', 'myFunction', 999);` so your filter is handled last. Or lower number to be handled earlier.

Comment: I've only experimented with 20 and empty. I'm try some large ones to see if that fixes it and then report back shortly.

Comment: @RST I tested it with 999, 0, -1, and 999999 and nothing seemed to have any effect on his site.

Comment: are there any other filters/actions added to the same hook in that theme? It should work the way you have it. The error could be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without more detail...but a good way to see what's going on is to output the hooks/ filters...

e.g.

```
function output_filters($filter) {
     global $wp_filter;

     if(!$filter)
        return;

     var_dump($wp_filter[$filter]);

} 

output_filters('the_content');
```